# Python rounding during rotation

Tags: python, rotation, rounding

I have a function that takes point(s) in 3D space, an angle measure, and the unit Vector that it rotates the points around.

```
def rotate(vertices, angle, unitV): #angle and unit vector that it rotates around

RotateMatrix = [[(math.cos(angle)+(unitV[0]*(1-math.cos(angle)))),(unitV[0]*unitV[1]*(1-math.cos(angle))-(unitV[2]*math.sin(angle))),(unitV[0]*unitV[2]*(1-math.cos(angle))+(unitV[1]*math.sin(angle)))],
                [(unitV[1]*unitV[0]*(1-math.cos(angle))+(unitV[2]*math.sin(angle))),(math.cos(angle)+(unitV[1]*(1-math.cos(angle)))),(unitV[1]*unitV[2]*(1-math.cos(angle))-(unitV[0]*math.sin(angle)))],
                [(unitV[2]*unitV[0]*(1-math.cos(angle))-(unitV[1]*math.sin(angle))),(unitV[2]*unitV[1]*(1-math.cos(angle))+(unitV[0]*math.sin(angle))),(math.cos(angle)+(unitV[2]*(1-math.cos(angle))))]
                ]

for i in range(len(vertices)):
    x = ((RotateMatrix[0][0]*vertices[i][0])+(RotateMatrix[0][1]*vertices[i][1])+(RotateMatrix[0][2]*vertices[i][2]))
    y = ((RotateMatrix[1][0]*vertices[i][0])+(RotateMatrix[1][1]*vertices[i][1])+(RotateMatrix[1][2]*vertices[i][2]))
    z = ((RotateMatrix[2][0]*vertices[i][0])+(RotateMatrix[2][1]*vertices[i][1])+(RotateMatrix[2][2]*vertices[i][2]))
    vertices[i]=([x,y,z])

return vertices
```

The Rotate Matrix comes from: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

The for loop just multiplies each vertice point by the rotation matrix, and then returns the new rotate point. The problem is when I try to rotate a point across a unit vector like [0.7071067811865476, 0.7071067811865475, 0.0]. For example when I rotate the point [0,5,0] around that unit vector:

`print rotate([[0,5,0]], math.radians(180), [0.7071067811865476, 0.7071067811865475, 0.0])`

it returns the new point as [5.0, 2.0710678118654746, 4.329780281177467e-16]. However, the new point should be exactly [5.0,0,0]. Obviously python doesnt round perfectly, but for some reason the points being returned from the function are always off. I triple checked the rotational matrix and the way it is multiplied to the points, so the only reason I could think of was a rounding error.

Thank you for any answers!

Comment: I'm not sure what the error is. What I would reccomend is that you break the steps down into pieces using the `assert` statement, and figure out where exactly the bug is. I would imagine it's something to do with what `vertices` contains (which we can't see).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I narrowed down the question a little so maybe the problem is a little easier to understand. Vertices contains a list of [x,y,z] coordinates (in this case just one coordiante).

Comment: I dunno, sorry. The math is a bit beyond me. It sure seems like a lot of multiplication for what you're trying to do though. From what I understand though, I'm wondering if maybe you want `vertices[0][i]` instead of `verticies[i][0]`; `vertices[1][i]` instead of `verticies[i][1]`.